# Upload handler with zip files and rar files

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I am using html input file to upload the files. Everything is working fine except in the case of .Zip or .rar. I am checking posted file in generic handler like:

```
HttpPostedFile PostedFile = context.Request.Files[0];

if (!(PostedFile == null))
{
    //do processing..
}
```

I tried image files, pdf, doc, even sql query files. Every type is uploading well, but with the case of .rar or .zip files I am not getting posted file into ashx handler. I mean every time I get an `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

I wonder how could I can post the .rar files or .zip files to handler. I am appending data in client side using form data like:

```
var form = $("#form1")[0];
var formdata = new FormData(form);
formdata.append('Data', JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }));
```

Comment: Have you tried checking with Fiddler (or any other watcher) to see that the request is actually sent and see the headers?

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file via AJAX?  That does not work natively.

Comment: ya..with ajax post!!! If it is so..how could i post zip files?? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get the file contents in the `context.Request.InputStream`. If yes then you can use following code:

```
    if (context.Request.InputStream != null && context.Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
    {
        System.IO.Stream fileContent = context.Request.InputStream;

        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/") + fileName);
        fileContent.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

        fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
```

Comment: oo yea!!! i could get filecontent here...!!! Let me complete it!! thanx for d idea!!!

Comment: are you trying to upload files asynchronously?